# Посчитать и вывести сумму всех значений в 1м поле mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер, нужно носчитать и вывести сумму всех значений в 1м поле в mysql.
Как это лучше сделать? посчитать сразу в mysql или вывести сначала и пусть php считает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(название поля) FROM имя таблицы WHERE условие

 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо, но...

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(amount) FROM bank");

А дальше как `$result` вывести? Если `echo` напрямую, то выводит `Resource id #5`.

Если пропустить через `mysql_fetch_array` и потом вывести - получается `Array` :)

Comment: Вопрос у тебя стоит иначе, ну немного подумать и дописать код.

Comment: да, это я уже успел понять)
но оно вывело кол-во строк, а мне нужна была сумма всего поля
т.е. имею две строки, в первой 20 во второй 5 и это в поле amount
нужно чтобы 25 вывело :)

Comment: быть может что то с типом поля. напиши все поля с их типами.

Comment: 4 поля:
id - int(10)

name - varchar

amount - int(10)

date - date

Comment: Даже и не знаю, откуда у тебя 2 строчки в результате, должна быть одна.попробуй **sum()** вместо **count()** а то я тут коньяк пью и наверное тебя дезинформировал :)

Count() вычисляет кол-во строк, sum() сумму значений.

Comment: Во! Хорош, спасибо) Выручил)